Cohen's d effect size of a medication
Studies use Cohen's d effect size to convey the effectiveness of an intervention. As a general rule in psychology, an effect size of 0.2 is considered small, 0.5 is medium, and 0.8 is large.
Suppose we have a large effect size of 0.8 between the placebo and intervention (drug X), then is it fair to interpret that 78.8% of people taking drug X will be above the mean of the group taking placebo?
That doesn't seem like a "large" effect because 50% of people in the placebo group would also be above the mean (assuming normal distribution).
So the drug is only effecting around 28% of the people? Or am I completely off-base?
Can the statistic also convey anything about the strength of the medication (e.g. change in quality of life score of 9/10 vs. 1/10) or it is simply used to measure binary outcomes (drug X had an effect, or did not have an effect, where we define effect to be 2/10 improvement).

To add to Peter Flom's answer: You say "As a general rule in psychology, an effect size of 0.2 is considered small, 0.5 is medium, and 0.8 is large." This has been criticized from the beginning by Jacob Cohen, who originally suggested these thresholds. He suggested to use them as a last resort, when there is no way of determining the practical relevance of an effect size. It seems you have some ideas of what a practically relevant ES would be, so it may be counterproductive to consider using those thresholds in the first place.

Have you seen this visualization tool, may be helpful though doesn't answer your question directly.

First, Cohen's $d$ is only one of many measures of effect size. In fact, there are quite a few measures of difference (which is what Cohen's $d$ measures).  $d$ may be appropriate but it may not.
Second, it is a single number summary, and the write-up of the intervention will have a lot more information, much of which will be useful.
Third, the formula for $d$ is
$d = \frac{\bar{x_1} - \bar{x_2}}{s}$
i.e. the difference of the means divided by the pooled standard deviation. (Means and sds may not be appropriate). You can't tell what the means are, just from $d$, but you can look them up. You give an example of 78.8 and 50 percent of two groups being above the mean. This is not enough information to calculate $d$ - you also need the sd - and d is not a test of difference of proportions. If you want a standardized measure of the difference of proportions, there are a few, including Cohen's $h$
$h = 2(\arcsin{\sqrt{p_1}} - \arcsin{\sqrt{p_2}})$
However, in an actual study, the researchers almost certainly did something more complex. Maybe logistic regression, maybe OLS regression, maybe Cox proportional hazards, maybe something else, depending on how the effect of the drug was measured.
Finally, Cohen's $d$ is, as I said, a measure of the difference between means. If the outcome is measured in terms of quality of life, then it will say something about quality of life (provided that the QOL measure is quantitative and that mean and sd are appropriate).
